# Hover div on top of youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I have a script which is making call for youtube feeds and then displays the video (no iframe)
Please take a look at the fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4pUE/)

I want to show an img on top of the player so I appended an img like this:

```
 html += '<span>Top Rated</span><img src="http://christianjamesphoto.com/themes/chrisjames/images/arrow-left.gif" /></div>';
```

and assigned to it a `z-index:9999;` However this doesnt seem to work. I have search for an answer to this and it seems that I have to put `wmode="transparent"` in to the link, but Im not sure how to implement this in the url. What can I do to make it show the img on top of the player?

Comment: The left arrow is showing on top of the player for me.  What browser are you testing on?

Comment: @Dcullen Im using chrome latest version. I also see the arrow but not all the time. Sometimes only when I scroll down but it keeps disapearing (its not stable). But this is only in Jsfiddle. When I look at it from my desktop I dont see an arrow at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new option to the jTubeEmbed plugin like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aFx29/2/

Changes:

```
    jTubeEmbed: function(video, options) {
        var options = $.extend({
            // Embed Options
            width: 560,
            height: 340,
            wmode: 'window', // can be window, transparent and opaque

            // Player Options
            autoplay: false,
            fullscreen: false,
            related: true,
            loop: false,
            keyboard: true,
            genie: false,
            border: false,
            highdef: true,
            start: 0
        }, options);

        // ... ommitted for brevity ...

        if(options.wmode) {
            videoEmbed += '<param name="wmode" value="' + options.wmode + '"></param>';
        }

        if(options.fullscreen == true) {
            videoEmbed += '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>';
        }

        videoEmbed += '<embed src="'+videoUrl+'"';
        videoEmbed += '    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"';

        if(options.wmode) {
            videoEmbed += '    wmode="' + options.wmode + '"';
        }

        if(options.fullscreen == true) {
            videoEmbed += '    allowfullscreen="true"';
        }

        videoEmbed += '    allowscriptaccess="always"';
        videoEmbed += '    width="'+options.width+'" height="'+options.height+'">';
        videoEmbed += '    </embed>';
        videoEmbed += '</object>';

        return videoEmbed;
    }
```

And pass in the option you want on the call for `jTubeEmbed` like:

```
$.jTubeEmbed(this.video, {
    // your options here,
    wmode: 'opaque'
});
```

Comment: It doesnt work on jsfiddle...same problem. It doesnt show on page load

Comment: I've just forgot to add the param to the call on the code, but the plugin was already changed. Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aFx29/2/

Answer (score 0):

The player is a flash object, to put an image on top you should consider:

[Display image above flash object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205497/display-image-above-flash-object)

Add this parameter to the videoEmbed:

```
videoEmbed += '<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>';
```

you can try something like this in your code:

```
html = '<li>';
html += '<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; z-index:2000;"><span>Top Rated</span>';
html += '<img src="http://christianjamesphoto.com/themes/chrisjames/images/arrow-left.gif" alt="" /></div>';
html += $.jTubeEmbed(this.video, embedOptions);
html += '<a href="'+this.link+'">'+this.title+'</a>';
html += '</li>';
```